# Preventing CloudFoundry from killing an application on OOM (out of memory)

Tags: java, out-of-memory, cloud-foundry

We have a Java application, deployed in CloudFoundry, that occasionally throws an OOM error, due to requests that have a large payload as result.
When this happens, CloudFoundry kills the app and restarts it.

When the application is running on a development machine (rather than in CF), the OOM does not result in a crash (but does display an "out of heap memory" message in the output); usually the request-handler thread ends and the memory that was allocated for the request is garbage-collected. The application continues to run and successfully serves more requests.

Is there a way to configure CF to avoid restarting the app on OOM?

Thanks.

Comment: How much memory are you using in your app?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.  The platform will always kill your app when you exceed the memory limit that you've assigned to it.  This is the intended behavior.  You cannot bypass this because that would essentially mean that your application has no memory limit.

On a side note, I would highly recommend using the Java buildpack v4.x (latest), if you are not already.  It is much better about configuring the JVM such that you get meaningful errors like JVM OOME's instead of just letting your application crash.  It also dumps helpful diagnostic information when this happens that will direct you to the source of the problem.

One other side note...

> the OOM does not result in a crash (but does display an "out of heap memory" message in the output); usually the request-handler thread ends and the memory that was allocated for the request is garbage-collected.

You don't want to rely on this behavior.  Once an OOME happens in the JVM, all bets are off.  It may be able to recover and it may put your application into a horrible and unusable state.  There's no way to know because there's no way to know exactly where the OOME will strike.  When you get an OOME, the best course of action is to obtain any diagnostic information that you need and restart.  This is exactly what the Java buildpack (v4+) does when your app runs on CF.

Hope that helps!